# Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

I try to use Google Sheets API and I do it like this:

```
var service = GTLRSheetsService()
let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet.query(withSpreadsheetId: SpreadSheetIdentifier, range: SpreadSheetRange)
service.apiKey = SpreadSheetApiKey
service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
```

but when I call that function get an error:

> Requests from this ios client application `<empty>` are blocked.

What am I missing?

My google sheet has access **Anyone with the link**.

Full response from google:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this ios client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/722884849069/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this.